# Htaccess issue which can't figured it out

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I have strange problem with `.htaccess` and urls. I have this in htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On 
       RewriteBase /sitesubfolder/

       RewriteRule ^test$ pages/test.php
</IfModule>
```

this on my href link

```
<a href="test/"> Link </a>
```

The site is in subfolder not in root dir and the path is `/var/www/www/site/`
When I go to the site url and click on the Link page refreshed but is staying on same page. If I click again url become **site.com/test/test/test**.. every new click on Link is just placing one more `/test/` to the page.

Server is nginx if is matter.

I've added this to `site.conf`

```
server {

     root   /var/www/www/site/;
     index  index.php index.html;

     location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
     }
   ....
}
```

But still same (I've reloaded nginx also)

Comment: `.htaccess` is an Apache file. You are using `nginx`.

Comment: Oh, didn't knew about this.. and there is no way to use it in `nginx`? How can I rewrite urls then and make "pretty" urls?

Comment: `nginx` is configured by `nginx.conf` or one of the files included into it. You need to look at your existing configuration, but that `.htaccess` is easily implemented using a [`try_files` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

Comment: @RichardSmith, thanks for the comments. So following the link I've updated my question with what I've added but the behavior is still same.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` to see exactly what `nginx` is using. Did you add a new`server` block to your existing configuration? Because that is the wrong solution.

Comment: No, I have 3 sites on this server and for each site I have different .conf file... site1.conf, site2.conf...`nginx -T` is returning all 3 `.conf` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your existing `.htaccess` file, it seems to me that the problem can be summarised as follows:

The document root is `/var/www/www/site`, there is a sub-folder `sitesubfolder` below it, containing another subfolder called `pages`.

When within the URI `/sitesubfolder`, the relative link `test/` (which the absolute link `/sitesubfolder/test/` should invoke `/var/www/www/site/sitesubfolder/pages/test.php`

There are many ways to achieve this, for example:

```
rewrite ^/sitesubfolder/test/$ /sitesubfolder/pages/test.php last;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Even I still have some issues this was very helpful starting point.